# Only get base class properties, not inheriting class, using reflection

Tags: c#

How can I use reflection to only get properties in a base class, not the inherited class.

Say my base class has a virtual method and the inheriting class overrides it. If the override calls base.MyMethod() then reflection within base.MyMethod() gets the properties from both classes or just the inheriting class, depending upon the BindingFlags are used.

Is there a way I can only access the properties in the base class?

Edit: Maybe some code will help explain why I want to do this.

```
internal static void Save(DataTransactionAccess data, string sproc, object obj)
{
  if (checkMandatoryProperties(obj))
  {
    saveToDatabase(data, sproc, obj);
  }
}

private static void saveToDatabase(DataTransactionAccess data, string sproc, object obj)
{
  List<object> paramList;
  PropertyInfo idProperty;
  populateSaveParams(out paramList, out idProperty, obj);
  if (idProperty != null)
  {
    int id = data.ExecuteINTProcedure(sproc, paramList.ToArray());
    idProperty.SetValue(obj, id, null);
  }
  else
  {
    data.ExecuteProcedure(sproc, paramList.ToArray());
  }
}

private static void populateSaveParams(out List<object> paramList, out PropertyInfo idProperty, object obj)
{
  paramList = new List<object>();
  idProperty = null;
  foreach (PropertyInfo info in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
  {
    if (info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SaveProperty), true).Length > 0)
    {
      paramList.Add("@" + info.Name);
      paramList.Add(info.GetValue(obj, null));
    }
    if (info.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SaveReturnIDProperty), true).Length > 0)
    {
      idProperty = info;
    }
  }
}
```

It is within the foreach loop in populateSaveParams that I need to get the properties for the class within obj that Save was called, not any classes it inherits from or any of its child classes.

Hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Are you using `GetType` or `typeof(BaseClass)` when inspecting it for values? I would think the latter would get just your baseclass values.

Comment: I can't use typeof(BaseClass) as this is for an extension method to an interface, so the underlying class needs to be determined at runtime using GetType().

Comment: Why does your extension method care about the base class then if it only knows of the interface? It sounds like your extension method is too broad.

Comment: The extension method creates the call to a save stored procedure, depending upon properties decorated with a custom attribute. Normally this works fine, but I have the requirement for a hierarchy of classes to have their own sproc and only save properties declared within the individual classes to be considered.

Comment: So each individual type in the type hierarchy has it's own Save step?

Comment: Yes, the base class has a save sproc and the inheriting class has its own.

Answer (score 1):

I came across a scenario where I needed a method to perform decision making based only on the base class properties.

So I filtered the properties of the instance this can be done in one of two ways as shown below,

Using the `BaseType` property on the `Type` and then call the `GetProperties` method,

```
var baseType = instance.GetType().BaseType;
var properties = baseType.GetProperties();
```

Using the [`DeclaringType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.declaringtype(v=vs.110).aspx) property to check whether it is from the base class or the derived class,

```
var type = instance.GetType();
var properties = type.GetProperties();
// properties = properties.Where(p => p.DeclaringType.FullName == typeof(SomeClass).FullName).ToArray();
properties = properties.Where(p => p.DeclaringType.FullName == type.BaseType.FullName).ToArray();
```

The below code snippet retrieves the base class properties and writes them to the output stream. [Here](http://rextester.com/XKBX72341) is the compile C# online link

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Employee (derived class) - Person (base class)
            var employee = new Employee
            {
                Company = "Stack Overflow",
                Designation = "Community Manager",
                FirstName = "Josh",
                LastName = "Heyer"
            };

            var baseType = employee.GetType().BaseType;
            var properties = baseType.GetProperties();
            var method = baseType.GetMethod("Print");

            for (var i = 0; i < properties.Count(); i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(properties[i].Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
            method.Invoke(employee, null);
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public virtual void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
        }
    }

    public class Employee : Person
    {
        public string Company { get; set; }

        public string Designation { get; set; }

        public override void Print()
        {
            base.Print();
            Console.WriteLine("Employment Details: {0} {1}", Company, Designation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider posting a revised answer, at the moment it just looks like a code dump and I doubt anyone has the time to sift through it to find the relevant information

Comment: @TheLethalCoder, thanks for the suggestion, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like a little bit of restructuring would be in order. Anything implementing the Interface would return a set of save operations:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
     IEnumerable<SaveStep> SaveData();
}

public class SomeClass : SomeBaseClass, ISomeInterface
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<SaveStep> SaveData()
    {
        foreach(var item in base.SaveData())
           yield return item;

        yield return new SaveStep { ... }
    }
}
```

Then you extension method (or any invoker really) just needs to invoke the `SaveData` method, and you get back a set of `SaveStep` objects you can use to constuct a procedure call with data based on whatever that class wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will consider it for future work. However, I would still like to know how to implement what I asked in my original question.

Comment: The only other way I could think to do it would be to inspect `GetType()` and recursively parse the `Type.BaseType` property while it's `!= typeof(object)` and then use that reference to parse it's properties.

Comment: Yes, that would do it, but I think I'd rather write larger, more complicated sprocs and not use the interface short cut. It does seem a bit daft that it is straight forward to do the opposite of what I want, only get the inherited class's properties, but not easy to it this way.

Comment: Well, technically, couldnt you do the inverse then? If you have a list of all properties, X, and then list of derived only properties Y, then you could theoretically do a non-intersection of the set of X and Y. But that would be *everything* that is not your most derived type.

Comment: Yes, but it would get pretty ugly if the class hierarchy was of any size. The one I'm working on now has three levels but others could be bigger. I don't think this is a technique that would blossom using recursion!

Comment: When you say "base class", do you mean the direct parent of your interface object? What needs to happen if you have a deeper hierarchy (for example, class `c` implements your interface and inherits from class `b`, and class `b` inherits from class `a`) - which of the base objects needs to be processed, `b` or `a`?

Comment: The extension method to the interface needs to identify the properties of each class and only those properties, not any inherited properties or properties from inheriting classes.